# Mysql update column with value from another table. Error: "count doesn't match"

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this situation:

TABLE `ASSET`

[image]

TABLE `USERS`

[image]

and now i wanna be delete name \surname columns on device table and fill id_users with relative id_users of users table.

Sample:

[image]

I've tried with these queries:

1)

```
 UPDATE asset t1 
            INNER JOIN users t2 
                 ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.surname = t2.surname
    SET t1.id_users = t2.id_users
```

2)

```
UPDATE asset 
    SET asset.id_users = (
        SELECT users.id_users
        FROM users
        WHERE asset.name = users.name AND asset.surname = users.surname
    );
```

Both queries I get this error :

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Can you help me??

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Your first query works for me. Are you sure you didn't miss anything when you copied it into the question? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06dea/1

Comment: no, not work. #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: The problem that I can see in the second query is that the SELECT for users.id_users can return more than one row. This might not be the case but you have to make sure that name and username are primary keys. This should not happen. Another solution should be if you add an aggregate function like MAX for the users.id_users.

Comment: ok, How? post a sample, please.